error: System.ExtrinsicFailed: NoProvider when deploying smart contract
I just installed pallet-contracts on my Frontier node.
From the Polkadot js app interface, I can send transactions with tokens without problems, but if I try to deploy a new smart contract (inside developer/contracts GUI), I get this:
✅ InstantateWithCode
❌ system.ExtrinsicFailed NoProvider
What does “NoProvider” means and why i get it? how can i resolve it?
thi is my contracts_config.rs:
use crate::{
    Balance, Balances, BalancesCall, Perbill, RandomnessCollectiveFlip, Runtime, RuntimeCall,
    RuntimeEvent, RuntimeHoldReason, Timestamp,
};
use frame_support::{
    parameter_types,
    traits::{ConstBool, ConstU32},
};
use frame_system::EnsureSigned;

pub enum AllowBalancesCall {}

impl frame_support::traits::Contains<RuntimeCall> for AllowBalancesCall {
    fn contains(call: &RuntimeCall) -> bool {
        matches!(call, RuntimeCall::Balances(BalancesCall::transfer_allow_death { .. }))
    }
}

// Unit = the base number of indivisible units for balances
const UNIT: Balance = 1_000_000_000_000;
const MILLIUNIT: Balance = 1_000_000_000;

const fn deposit(items: u32, bytes: u32) -> Balance {
    (items as Balance * UNIT + (bytes as Balance) * (5 * MILLIUNIT / 100)) / 10
}

fn schedule<T: pallet_contracts::Config>() -> pallet_contracts::Schedule<T> {
    pallet_contracts::Schedule {
        limits: pallet_contracts::Limits {
            runtime_memory: 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
            ..Default::default()
        },
        ..Default::default()
    }
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const DepositPerItem: Balance = deposit(1, 0);
    pub const DepositPerByte: Balance = deposit(0, 1);
    pub Schedule: pallet_contracts::Schedule<Runtime> = schedule::<Runtime>();
    pub const DefaultDepositLimit: Balance = deposit(1024, 1024 * 1024);
    pub const CodeHashLockupDepositPercent: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(0);
    pub const MaxDelegateDependencies: u32 = 32;
}

impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Time = Timestamp;
    type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type CallFilter = AllowBalancesCall;
    type DepositPerItem = DepositPerItem;
    type DepositPerByte = DepositPerByte;
    type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 23];
    type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Self>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type ChainExtension = ();
    type Schedule = Schedule;
    type AddressGenerator = pallet_contracts::DefaultAddressGenerator;
    type MaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 128 * 1024 }>;
    type DefaultDepositLimit = DefaultDepositLimit;
    type MaxStorageKeyLen = ConstU32<128>;
    type MaxDebugBufferLen = ConstU32<{ 2 * 1024 * 1024 }>;
    type UnsafeUnstableInterface = ConstBool<false>;
    type CodeHashLockupDepositPercent = CodeHashLockupDepositPercent;
    type MaxDelegateDependencies = MaxDelegateDependencies;
    type RuntimeHoldReason = RuntimeHoldReason;
    type Environment = ();
    type Debug = ();
    type ApiVersion = ();
    type Migrations = ();
    #[cfg(not(feature = "parachain"))]
    type Xcm = ();
    type UploadOrigin = EnsureSigned<Self::AccountId>;
    type InstantiateOrigin = EnsureSigned<Self::AccountId>;
}

And my runtime lib:
mod contracts_config;

..code...

pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    pallet_contracts::Migration<Runtime>,
>;

..code..


const NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(75);


// Prints debug output of the `contracts` pallet to stdout if the node is
// started with `-lruntime::contracts=debug`.
const CONTRACTS_DEBUG_OUTPUT: pallet_contracts::DebugInfo =
    pallet_contracts::DebugInfo::UnsafeDebug;
const CONTRACTS_EVENTS: pallet_contracts::CollectEvents =
    pallet_contracts::CollectEvents::UnsafeCollect;

/// We allow for 2000ms of compute with a 6 second average block time.
pub const WEIGHT_MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK: u64 = 2000;
pub const MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT: Weight = Weight::from_parts(
    WEIGHT_MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK * WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_MILLIS,
    u64::MAX,
);
pub const MAXIMUM_BLOCK_LENGTH: u32 = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

 impl pallet_insecure_randomness_collective_flip::Config for Runtime {}

...code...

// Create the runtime by composing the FRAME pallets that were previously configured.
#[frame_support::runtime]
mod runtime {
    #[runtime::runtime]
    #[runtime::derive(
        RuntimeEvent,
        RuntimeCall,
        RuntimeError,
        RuntimeOrigin,
        RuntimeFreezeReason,
        RuntimeHoldReason,
        RuntimeSlashReason,
        RuntimeLockId,
        RuntimeTask
    )]
    pub struct Runtime;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(0)]
    pub type System = frame_system;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(1)]
    pub type Timestamp = pallet_timestamp;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(2)]
    pub type Aura = pallet_aura;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(3)]
    pub type Grandpa = pallet_grandpa;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(4)]
    pub type Balances = pallet_balances;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(5)]
    pub type TransactionPayment = pallet_transaction_payment;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(6)]
    pub type Sudo = pallet_sudo;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(7)]
    pub type Ethereum = pallet_ethereum;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(8)]
    pub type EVM = pallet_evm;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(9)]
    pub type EVMChainId = pallet_evm_chain_id;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(10)]
    pub type BaseFee = pallet_base_fee;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(11)]
    pub type ManualSeal = pallet_manual_seal;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(12)]
    pub type PalletCustom = pallet_custom;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(13)]
    pub type Contracts = pallet_contracts;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(14)]
    pub type RandomnessCollectiveFlip = pallet_insecure_randomness_collective_flip;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(15)]
    pub type Assets = pallet_assets;
}

..code...


impl_runtime_apis! {

    impl pallet_contracts::ContractsApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber, Hash, EventRecord>
        for Runtime
    {
        fn call(
            origin: AccountId,
            dest: AccountId,
            value: Balance,
            gas_limit: Option<Weight>,
            storage_deposit_limit: Option<Balance>,
            input_data: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts::ContractExecResult<Balance, EventRecord> {
            let gas_limit = gas_limit.unwrap_or(BlockWeights::get().max_block);
        
            Contracts::bare_call(
                origin,
                dest,
                value,
                gas_limit,
                storage_deposit_limit,
                input_data,
                CONTRACTS_DEBUG_OUTPUT,
                CONTRACTS_EVENTS,
                pallet_contracts::Determinism::Enforced,
            )
        }

        fn instantiate(
            origin: AccountId,
            value: Balance,
            gas_limit: Option<Weight>,
            storage_deposit_limit: Option<Balance>,
            code: pallet_contracts::Code<Hash>,
            data: Vec<u8>,
            salt: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts::ContractInstantiateResult<AccountId, Balance, EventRecord>
        {
            let gas_limit = gas_limit.unwrap_or(BlockWeights::get().max_block);
            Contracts::bare_instantiate(
                origin,
                value,
                gas_limit,
                storage_deposit_limit,
                code,
                data,
                salt,
                CONTRACTS_DEBUG_OUTPUT,
                CONTRACTS_EVENTS,
            )
        }

        fn upload_code(
            origin: AccountId,
            code: Vec<u8>,
            storage_deposit_limit: Option<Balance>,
            determinism: pallet_contracts::Determinism,
        ) -> pallet_contracts::CodeUploadResult<Hash, Balance>
        {
            Contracts::bare_upload_code(origin, code, storage_deposit_limit, determinism)
        }

        fn get_storage(
            address: AccountId,
            key: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts::GetStorageResult {
            Contracts::get_storage(address, key)
        }
    }
    ..code..
 }

..code..


I encountered the same error, and I found out the error might generated in the following code snippet from frame-system crate(mine was version 28.0.0) when I'm trying to dig deeper.

I changed the ExistentialDeposit configuration in runtime/lib.rs to a nonzero amount, and the error was solved. Since in the contract instantiation part, ExistentialDeposit amount coins were supposed to transfer to the contract address, when the ExistentialDeposit equals to 0, then the contract can't be instantiated.

Is there a way around it? i.e. can we eliminate this NoProviders error when the ED is zero?
